# push_back a char from a string to another string

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I'm trying to append some characters from one string to another, but I couldn't do it. I tried something like this:

```
std::string fooz = "fooz";
std::string foo;
int i = 0;
while(i< fooz.length()){
    if(fooz[i] != 'z'){
       foo.push_back(fooz[i]);
    }
    i++;
}
```

foo after the while its empty.

Comment: Your loop can be simplified into `std::copy_if`.

Comment: Typo. Should be `while(i< fooz.length()){`

Answer (score 4):

You're taking length from the target string, which is still empty and the while loop won't be executed at all.

Change

```
while(i< foo.length()){
```

to

```
while(i< fooz.length()){
```

Comment: I was about to say the same.

Comment: I know there is a problem there, but foo still empty after the while, thats my problem

Comment: @IgnacioTarrio I tried a demo [here](http://rextester.com/CJRX67493), it should work well. Is it your all code? There might be some other issues elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The STL can help you in this kind of scenarios.

This one uses the [remove](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove/?kw=remove) algorithm which provide a range of element to erase.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string str("aaazbbb");

    std::cout << str << std::endl;

    str.erase(std::remove(str.begin(), str.end(), 'z'), str.end());

    std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
std::string fooz = "fooz";
std::string foo;
int i = 0;
int len=fooz.size();
while(i< len){
    if(fooz[i] != 'z'){
       foo.push_back(fooz[i]);
    }
    i++;
}
```

Don not call std::string.size() or length() in while loop.

Comment: The author answer is wrong in this case.  It's generally bad practice to call it on something that's changing (you can't do it with iterators either without "bad stuff" potentially happening, for example), but doesn't matter much here.  If the compiler is "really with it" it'll optimize away the repeated call to the method, making it just as efficient as he has here.